# Look at each element during parentsUntil

Tags: jquery, css

I want to essentially do this :

```
$('#myelement').parentsUntil( ".myStopper" ).css("overflow","visible");
```

But as it is looping through each of the parent elements i'd like to check each element for the existence of a css attribute "max-width", and id that attribute is present i'd like to skip applying the overflow:visible css to that element, and move to the next parent.

I was hoping to be able to form a function out of the parentsUntil, but can't really see how to syntax that if it's even possible.

Kind regards
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#myelement').parentsUntil( ".myStopper" ).each(function(){

  if($(this).css('max-width').length == 0 && $(this).attr('id').length==0)
   {
      $(this).css("overflow","visible");
   } 

});
```

Comment: Thank's that looks very understandable to me. One question though..Why are you testing if the element has an id, or is this just as an example of what is possible..?

Comment: As per your statement ' id that attribute is present i'd like to skip applying the overflow:visible css to that element,' I thought you were checking it. May be I understood it wrongly. If you don't want that check just remove it.

Comment: Ahhh.. typo in my question.. id = if .. sorry about that. Perfect answer accepted. thanks again :-)